# what does this sql query do? SELECT column_1 FROM table_1,table_2;

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

```
SELECT column_1 FROM table_1,table_2;
```

When I ran this on my database it returned huge number of rows with duplicate column_1 values. I could not understand why I got these results. Please explain what this query does.

Comment: selects column_1 from table1, table 2 without any join condition. you Need to add a condition like `where table1.id = table2.id`

Comment: Perhaps to little effort. No sample data, no expected result. Arbitrary dbms tagging etc.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In more layman's terms, it means that for each record in Table A, you get every record from Table B (all possible combinations).

TableA with 3 records and Table B with 3 records gives 9 total records in the result:

```
TableA-1/B-1
TableA-1/B-2
TableA-1/B-3
TableA-2/B-1
TableA-2/B-2
TableA-2/B-3
TableA-3/B-1
TableA-3/B-2
TableA-3/B-3
```

Often used as a basis for Cartesian Queries (which themselves are the means to generate, say, a list of future dates based on a recurrence schedule: give me all possible results for the next 6 months, then restrict that set to those whose factor matches my day of the week)

Answer (score 4):

it gives you a [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) from table 1 and table 2

Comment: What would be the use of this. Can you give an example?

Comment: @serbia99 I have no idea. i never needed it

Comment: look at Dymeng's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is 'valid' way of cross joining two tables; it is not the preferred way though. `Cross Join` would be much clearer. An `on` condition would then be helpful to limit results,

Comment: So its just another way of doing a CROSS JOIN. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that i have 3 friends named Jhon, Ana, Nick; then i have in the other table 2 are T-shirts a red and a yellow and i wanna know witch is from.

So in the query being tableA:Friends and tableB:Tshirts returns:

```
1|JHON | t-shirt_YELLOW
2|JHON | t-shirt_RED
3|ANA  | t-shirt_YELLOW
4|ANA  | t-shirt_RED
5|NICK | t-shirt_YELLOW
6|NICK | t-shirt_RED
```

As you see this join has no relational logic between friends and Tshirts so by evaluating all the posible **combination** generates what you call duplicates.